# perl increment month with localtime

Tags: perl, date

i have a date $time2 and want to increment by one month up to 07/01/2015 (07/0/2015, 07/03/2015, 07/04/2015, ...).

increment by one day works fine:

```
$t2 = strftime( "%m/%d/%Y", localtime( $time2 + 24 * 3600));   # 07/01/2013
```

increment by one month i have an error:

```
my $t02 = strftime( "%m/%d/%Y", localtime( $time2 + 0 * 3600));  
my @t22 = ($t02 =~ m|(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})| );  
$t22[1]++;      
$t2 = $t22[0]."/".$t22[1]."/".$t22[1];
```

have error`Month '-1' out of range 0..11`
how to fix it?
[codei HERE](http://pastebin.com/6eDC4T56)

Comment: Can you just paste the value of `$time2` as is? What you are trying to achieve here? Mention sample input and desired output. People may suggest smarter approach to solve it, rather than just correcting your error.

Comment: The code you posted that not issue that error (or any output whatsoever (after adding the missing `use POSIX qw( strftime );`)). That error comes from `timelocal` or `timegm`, which you didn't use. Please provide code that actually demonstrates your error

Comment: Note that not all days have 24 hours. 24 * 3600 will not always work. You should use something like [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime)

Comment: @jkshah: $time2 is not a human readable date value ( 1690948800 ) that is why i am using localtime to format it

Comment: @mamesaye I got it from use of localtime. I didn't want to read it. I want to try your code at my end and needed to give that same input. Thanks!

Comment: @ikegami: the error comes from looping as you said all months are not equal. i have `use Time::Local; use POSIX qw/strftime/;` in the beginning of the script. I updated with code link.Thanks

Comment: Consider POSIX::mktime, or use one of the specialist date/time Perl classes — there are many to choose from on http://search.cpan.org/.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use POSIX qw(strftime mktime);

my $time2 = 1690948800;

my @parts = localtime $time2;

$parts[4]++; # increment month

print strftime('%m/%d/%Y', localtime $time2), "\n";
print strftime('%m/%d/%Y', localtime mktime @parts), "\n";
```

But `Time::Piece` is pretty handy, too.

Comment: it is working partially... february is skipped!? goes from january to march. $VAR1 = 't2 : 01/30/2021';
$VAR1 = 't2 : 03/02/2021

Comment: What date in January are you using?  Would you have wanted (the last day in February) or (February 30th, 2021)?  That's probably a good argument for using `Time::Piece` or `DateTime`.  Dates are tricky.

Comment: Thanks, will git it a try

Comment: DateTime worked for me.   `my $dt = DateTime->new( year => $tval22[0], month => $tval22[1], day => $tval22[2] );   $dt->add( months => 1, end_of_month => 'limit' );` Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use integer;

sub udt2st {
    my $t = shift;
    my ($y, $m, $d) = (localtime($t))[5, 4, 3]; $y += 1900; $m++;
    return [$y * 10000 + $m * 100 + $d, $y, $m, $d];
};

my $starttime = time();
my ($yyyymmdd, $y, $m, $d) = @{&udt2st($starttime)};
while ($yyyymmdd < 20150701) {
    #
    print sprintf(qq/%s %04d-%02d-%02d\n/, $yyyymmdd, $y, $m, $d); # working stuff here
    #
    my $il = (($y + 3) % 4 / 3) >> (($y + 99) % 100 / 99); # is leap?
    my $md = 30 + (($m + $m / 8) % 2) - (($m + 9) % 12) / 11 * (2 - $il); # max. day in this month
    $starttime += (($md - $d) + $d) * 86400;
    ($yyyymmdd, $y, $m, $d) = @{&udt2st($starttime)};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd opt for a shorter version using bash

```
for m in {0..12}; do date -ud "01/07/2015 +$m month" +"%m/%d/%Y"; done
```

The result gives 13 date strings, each on its own line. You can use $time2 and collect the output into perl using backticks. Here's a sample from the output:

01/07/2015 02/07/2015
... 01/07/2016

The problem that you mention happens when 'date' is trying to calculate a day one month away from the 30th of January. Here's an example

```
for m in {0..12}; do date -ud "01/30/2015 +$m month" +"%m/%d/%Y"; done
```

01/30/2015
03/02/2015
03/30/2015
04/30/2015
.... 12/30/2015
01/30/2016

There will still be 13 date strings listed, but the second and third ones state a date in March. This is since March 2nd is one month away from January 30th and March 30th is two months away from January 30th.

That's life

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work on systems where `date` implements only the POSIX set of options. For example, on FreeBSD 9 there are just usage errors with this line.

Comment: Well, on freeBSD the date command has a different prototype. Here's the command you should invoke: `for m in {0..12}; do  date -v7d -v1m -v2015y -v+${m}m +'%m/%d/%Y'; done`

Answer (score -2):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use POSIX qw(mktime strftime);

my $year_from_now = getDateYearFromNow("%Y%m%d");
exit;
        
sub getDateYearFromNow
{    
    my ($format) = @_;
    my @now = localtime();
    $now[3] += 365; ## same time, 1 year from now
    my $f = strftime $format, localtime(mktime(@now));
    return $f;
}
```